# DjVu thumbnails are not being generated at all

Tags: thumbnails, mediawiki, djvu

I have DjVu installed on a MediaWiki wiki, but the thumbnails are not being generated at all.

I'm getting the DjVu logo and "(0 × 0 pixels, file size: 13.36 MB, MIME type: image/vnd.djvu)"

What can be done to make the thumbnails generate as they should?

Comment: For starters, check the [logs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug#Logging).

Comment: @Tgr I did check the logs, and don't see anything that explains why the thumbnails aren't generating..

Comment: After more digging, I found "DjVu XML metadata is invalid or missing, should have been fixed in upgradeRow", but I'm not sure what this means and if this is the cause.

Comment: It is most likely because the files were imported prior to the libraries being added. How can I regenerate the DjVu thumbnails?

Comment: Try [refreshImageMetadata.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:RefreshImageMetadata.php).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the files just need to be completely reuploaded.